# git set upstream to origin

Tags: git, github

I have been reading about & using git but am still confused about the term "origin".

I have a local repo and I made a new branch on it. This new branch is a copy from my master.

My master is a fork of the original master, another repo made by someone else, and is ahead of the original master by some commits and behind in some other.

I want to merge my branch "myBranch" with the original master. ie, I want my new branch to be a clone of the original master (not my own master)

**How to go?**

I have tried git rebase, git merge, --set-upstream-to=, git fetch... and to be honest I'm just confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'origin' is just the default name given by git to a remote repository - in your case your fork at github. You can override that name to something more meaningful if you wish. (I often use 'github' or 'bitbucket' instead of 'origin').

Your local master branch is probably tracking the master branch on the remote repository. That will allow you to push changes from your master to the remote master using

```
    git checkout master
    git push origin master
```

To deal with the changes from your new branch, you need to merge them into your local master first:

```
    git checkout master
    git merge mybranch
```

then, you'll be able to push those changes to the remote repo.

You can then create a 'pull request' on github so that the original owner can merge your changes into their repo if they wish.

To bring your fork up to date with changes from the original, you'll need to add another remote to your local repository:

```
    git remote add original <url to orginal github repo>
```

then you can fetch changes from there to your local repo:

```
    git checkout master
    git fetch original
    git rebase original/master
```

and merge them into mybranch, if you wish:

```
    git checkout mybranch
    git rebase master
```

Comment: Owen, thanks for the input! I think my confusion is _"which is the remote?"_ My fork of that repo (on my github account) or the original from where I forked in the first place?

Comment: Your fork on github. You can't push changes to the original. You have to create a pull request for the owner of that repo.

Comment: What I want is rebase my local branch, not to push. To make it a clone of the original master (the one I do not own)

Comment: Then you need to bring your local master branch up to date with 'git pull', checkout your 'mybranch' and then rebase from master. I'll add some more to my answer to make this clearer/

Comment: If you are not making any changes that you wish to push to the original repo, then you don't need a fork at all. Just clone the original to your local machine